# Trapped in the code: spacing and punctuation next to dollar signs prevents ending paragraphs and environments

Tags: support, mathjax

Here is a weird bug (or unexpected feature) in the MarkDown engines, probably tex related.

```
 ($ \{a,b\} $) now you can never leave the code block.
Not on a new line.

Not in a new paragraph.

You are forever in the code block.

Until you say the magic word, open-parenthesis dollar-sign: ($
```

New line for a new world.

New paragraph to celebrate the new me.

Comment: For low rep users, what I typed is available at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/2332/revisions  and more directly at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/revisions/d3ffc77f-4735-4444-a279-c5b839b2cc61/view-source

Comment: See also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559/paragraph-break-not-rendered-when-formulas-end-in-spaces

Comment: it may be a bug, but it is also one that it out of our control - it is a MathJax bug and not something we, at Stack Exchange can fix.  _(ed ajf)_

Comment: Actually the bug has been fixed already, as you can see if you click "edit" on the question and look at the preview. At some point StackExchange must have changed their Markdown-to-HTML converter to fix the problem, but IIRC the generated HTML is not updated for existing posts, like this one, unless someone actually edits the content. So let's mark this [status-completed] and drop the matter.

Comment: @Rahul: That might be, but the truth is that the preview render code is different from the final render code. So it might not be as solved as you might think.

Answer (score 9):

A few observations: `($ \{a,b\}` is completely optional and has nothing to do with what you observe, so here's a smaller example

```
 $ now you can never leave the code block.
Not on a new line.

Not in a new paragraph.

You are forever in the code block.

Until you say the magic word: dollar sign. $
```

Similarly,

```
($ $ again you can't leave the code block.

Not on a new line.

Not in a new paragraph.

You are forever in the code block.

$ on we go until we don't know what nonsensical stuff to write and hit enter
```

and that brings us out.

The first dollar sign seems to be ignored by the engine due to the parenthesis right before it while the second opens a block which is then closed by the last dollar sign.

It doesn't seem to work with the back-ticked code blocks.

The block quote environment:

> $ in a block quote we (new line) 
> we have a similar
>
> thing: new lines and new paragraphs are ignored.$ and

out we go

> ($ $ just another test
> new line
>
> new paragraph 
> $ and

out we are.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's been fixed already. Here's exactly the same Markdown code from the question, copy-pasted into a new answer for [Asaf's](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2332/trapped-in-the-code-spacing-and-punctuation-next-to-dollar-signs-prevents-endin/16304#comment59321_2332) benefit:

---

Here is a weird bug (or unexpected feature) in the MarkDown engines, probably tex related.

```
 ($ \{a,b\} $) now you can never leave the code block.
```

Not on a new line.

Not in a new paragraph.

You are forever in the code block.

Until you say the magic word, open-parenthesis dollar-sign: ($
New line for a new world.

New paragraph to celebrate the new me.

Comment: So, are we friends with benefits now? :-P